# Calling content areas new content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-area, content-builder

We are trying to dynamically call for content areas within an email using the `ContentArea` function. We have no issues calling content areas that were created using the classic content builder, but when we try to do the same and call to a content area that was created using the new Content builder we get an error. Is this not available with the new content builder areas? or is the syntaxes different?

Example:

```
%%[
Var @CRI 
Set @CRI = Contact_Row_id
]%%
%%=v(@CRI)=%%

%%[
Var @Product
Set @Product = Lookup("Asset_Test","Product_name", "Contact_Row_id",@CRI)]%%
%%=v(@Product)=%%
%%=ContentArea("1160")=%%
```

We get the following error:

> The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct
>   all issues, and try again. An error occurred when attempting to
>   evaluate an ContentArea function call.  Function Call:
>   ContentArea("1160")  See inner exception for details. The specified
>   content area client does not match the job client.  ContentAreaID:
>   1160  Job ClientID:   Content ClientID:   Function Name:
>   ContentArea  Parameter Name: ContentID  Parameter Ordinal: 1 
>   Parameter Type: Numeric  Submitted Value: 1160  ClientID: 
>   JobID: 0  ListID: 0  BatchID: 0  SubcriberID: 0  Data Source Type:
>   CustomObject  Data Source ID: 99c19049-eb48-e611-8bd1-38eaa7313839

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Content Builder Blocks, you need to use [ContentBlockByID](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentblockbyid6/) or [ContentBlockByKey](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentblockbykey/) to call them.  The Content area functions are only for classic email editor.